# redis refuses to start

Tags: redis, ubuntu-15.04

I've installed redis according to [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis). Everything works fine until I run `sudo service redis_6379 start` at which point I get the error
`Failed to start redis_6379.service: Unit redis_6379.service failed to load: No such file or directory.`

When I check I see that redis is not running:

```
> sudo service redis_6379 status
● redis_6379.service
Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
Active: inactive (dead)
```

I'm not sure what this `redis_6379.service` file is, or how I can create it? any help?

EDIT: tried installing using `sudo apt-get install redis-server` and got the following errors:

```
adduser: Warning: The home directory `/var/lib/redis' does not belong to the user that you are currently creating.
insserv: script shlonsky: service nginx already provided!
insserv: script unicorn_my_app: service unicorn already provided!
insserv: warning: script 'vncserver' missing LSB tags and overrides
insserv: There is a loop between service unicorn and vncserver if stopped
insserv:  loop involving service vncserver at depth 2
insserv:  loop involving service unicorn at depth 1
insserv: Stopping vncserver depends on unicorn_faisal_lab and therefore on system facility `$all' which can not be true!
insserv: exiting now without changing boot order!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package redis-server (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.21-0ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (219-7ubuntu6) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 redis-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I created recall creating the scripts `shlonsky` and `unicorn_my_app` to start nginx and unicorn, but I didn't think they would affect further .service instillation. any idea what I need to do to allow .service files to install?

Comment: Are you running ubuntu?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try installing redis-server simply through apt-get:
`sudo apt-get install redis-server`, after that simply `start`/`stop`/`restart` the server using `sudo service redis-server start` OR you should also be able to start the redis-server in the background manually using `redis-server &`.

Comment: After starting the server you should be able to connect to the redis command line interface (cli) using the `redis-cli` command.

Comment: You might have a broken (or valid) installation of redis in your system, do you have the `redis-server` command available at the command line ? If you do, have you tried running it?